# How to reference the values of different columns in a dataframe depending upon the data in them

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of records of varying lengths, with NAs at the end. If there are more than three x-values in a record, I want to make the value of the third x-value equal to the value of the last x-value. Each record already tells me how many x-values it has.
I can make x3 be equal to the name of the last x-value (x4 or x5 etc) but what I really need is to make x3 take the **value** of that last x-value.

I'm sure there is some simple answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Here is a simple case:

```
ii <- "n x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
1      3 30 40 20 NA NA NA
2      4 10 50 16 25 NA NA
3      6 20 15 26 16 18 28
4      5 10 10 18 17 19 NA
5      2 65 41 NA NA NA NA   
6      5 10 11 23 16 23 NA
7      1 99 NA NA NA NA NA"
df <- read.table(text=ii, header = TRUE, na.strings="NA", colClasses="character")

oo <- "n x1 x2 x3
1      3 30 40 20
2      4 10 50 25
3      6 20 15 28
4      5 10 10 19
5      2 65 41 NA
6      5 10 11 23
7      1 99 NA NA"
desireddf <- read.table(text=oo, header = TRUE, na.strings="NA", colClasses="character")

df$lastx <- as.character(paste("x", df$n, sep=""))
#df$lastx <- df[[get(df$lastx)]]   #How can I make lastx equal to the _value_ of lastx???
df[df$n>3, c('x3')] <- df[df$n>3, 'lastx']

df <- df[,1:4]
print(df)
```

yields the following, not the desireddf above.

```
  n x1   x2   x3
1 3 30   40   20
2 4 10   50   x4
3 6 20   15   x6
4 5 10   10   x5
5 2 65   41 <NA>
6 5 10   11   x5
7 1 99 <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a pretty aribtrary task, but here goes:

```
desireddf <- data.frame(n=df$n, x1=df$x1, x2=df$x2, x3=df[cbind(1:nrow(df), paste("x", pmax(3,as.numeric(df$n)), sep=""))])
```

Comment: I think you can shorten this to `cbind(df[1:3], x3 = df[cbind(1:nrow(df), pmax(4, as.integer(df$n) + 1))])`

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions. This is my first post to stackoverflow and it's amazing to me how quickly you helped me. My actual problem is more complicated than my sample case, and I'm thinking maybe I oversimplified. When I try a variation of your solutions (that also works on the test case) on my real case, I get a  "Error in as.matrix(x)[i] : subscript out of bounds" error. Here's that variation:  df4 <- cbind(df[1:3], x3 = df[cbind(1:nrow(df), paste("x", pmax(3,as.numeric(df$n)), sep=""))])     My real example has many more columns and column names more complicated than x1 x2 x3.

Comment: Not surprising as our answers use the column names you provided in the test case. Hopefully you can work out how to generalize the solutions a bit :)